# Cave texture stretches itself

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a research project for which I have to model a cave. I've done that, but I have a problem with the texture: As you can see in the images below, in the beginning the texture is quite random and looks like sandstone. In the end, however, it stretches into lines, which doesn't look that real. How do you fix this?

[image: inside the cave]
[image: outside the cave]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome, Sics9. No  image attached.

Comment: Yes please add an image